# Creating iframe widget with React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, widget, embed

I've made a widget in React that is meant to be embedded on other people's websites (think Drift/Intercom chat at the bottom right-hand corner of a webpage). First, there's a button, then when it's clicked a form pops up. Both the button and the form are inside a `<Widget />` component.

I am now trying to get this into an iframe and bundle the application into a single .js file so others can embed it on their site like the following:

```
<script src="https://website.com/widget.js">
<script>
    Widget.mount({id: 1})
</script
```

The `widget.js` file is the actual application, while the script below it is for passing in some props.

What I'm stuck on is how to do I get the Widget component into an iframe and have the iframe resize depending on whether the button is shown or the form is shown. I have tried using libraries like react-frame-component and react-frame, but neither seem to work. Zoid is also something that I've tried but it seems like I can't dynamically resize the iframe for the button/form.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact question a few months ago, so I can understand the confusion you have with the whole process.

This is the resource that was a game-changer for me (written by someone who directly worked on the Drift widget): https://medium.com/@ryan.da.baker/how-to-build-an-embedded-widget-with-react-redux-52a26604ccca

You can also use the Weasl widget source code that he references as a guide throughout the process: https://github.com/Rdbaker/weasl-widget

If you have some questions after looking some of this over, try to reach out to me, not exactly sure how to do that on here.

Comment: Thanks for this! When you did this, did you have the same problem of resizing the iframe based on the component being shown?

Comment: Yes.  When the button is clicked you are going to want to change the styles on the iframe.  To do this, you need something communicating between your widget and the website the widget is on.  That is what the shim and window.parent.postMessage() accomplish.  Once you understand the architecture of the Weasl widget, you will be able to answer questions you may have.  It took me some time reading the article and source code to internalize the architecture behind the solution.